# Parsing a column using shell scripting

Tags: shell, sqoop

I have a sqoop command in a shell script that returns a one column one row output like this:

[image]

Can you please help me with parsing this above output to get only the value 0? Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Fravadona, thank you for the response. using the above command didn't return anything. I'm trying to get the value 100 from that table

Comment: in the example, the value is 0 right? Otherwise if you know it should be 100 why need to parse the output?

Comment: Hi @Gildux, Sorry the value is 0, I edited the post. I'm trying to fetch the 0 so that I can store it in a variable as the next step.

Comment: OK, I've made an answer while you were replying too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your image:
[image]
…you're needing the forlast line, right?
Piping the the output to `tail -n 2` should answer

```
| 0           |
---------------
```

and from there pipe then to `head -n 1` and voila.

Another approche can be to remove dash lines with `grep -v -e '^--*$' to have

```
| Identifier  |
| 0           |
```

and from there, pipe then to `tail -n 1` to retrieve the last line.

Finally, pipe to `cut -d ' ' -f 2` or `awk '{print $2}'`

---

A refinement, if you want, will be to do the full stuff with `sed` or `awk` only.

If you are sure you have one column and two rows (the header and the data), the desired line is the fourth

```
1. ----------------
2. | Identifier   |
3. ----------------
4. | 0            |
5. ----------------
```

So, with `sed` just remove the leading "pipe-space" and trailing "spaces-pipe" of that line:

```bash
$sqoop_command | sed -e '4s/\(^| \)\|\(  *|$\)//g'
```

Here, `awk` may look easier when known:

```bash
$sqoop_command | awk 'FNR == 4 {print $2}'
```

Comment: Yes, add now the last part, `| awk '{print $2}'` and you'll have only `0` ;)

Comment: Also can you please tell me about the refinement you mentioned? it will be a great learning curve.

Comment: I've edited my answer to add the refinement. I'm not sure it's usefull at that stage if you are not used to `awk` or `sed` where those solutions are simple but may look like strange incantations when you're a newby in that field. As they are trivial (to me), I don't knwo what part need further explanations.